# How to overcome NodeJS heap memory error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a connected database in my NodeJS with 723.1 MB in size but facing the same trouble about memory size.

What I am doing is am making my database as API so that I can request it in my VueJS. I successfully render all the data as API needed using my dummy database which is only 0.1 MB in size.

What I already tried is to increase the memory allocated in node using this code

```
 node --max-old-space-size=2048 index.js
```

But nothing happens, I faced the same issue. What can I do to solve this kind of problem?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to send the whole database content as the response of API?

Comment: @shaochuancs no, I just want to limit it and just display some on my table

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing old space size to 4096 rather than 2048

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I used LIMIT CLAUSE just to display on my table.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY F_NAME LIMIT 1000
```

It was a dumb idea to display whole database on my frontend and it exceeds the limit of NODEJS that's why I faced the issue but came to my mind that I will just limit it and it works obviously.